# Remote Desktop Automatically changing screen size

Tags: remote-desktop

So, I'm using a Windows 7 laptop to Remote Desktop to my XP machine at work. I set it for full screen and log in. All is good. If I walk away, and my laptop goes to screen saver, the remote desktopm session always resizes to be a smaller size when I wake it up. Why is this? Can it be prevented? I've heard CNTRL-ALT-BREAK will force it back to full screen, but can this be prevented? It never happened with my old XP laptop when I remote desktopped from it to the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give it a try:

1. Go to **Control Panel**
2. Click on **Ease of Access link** or **Ease of Access Center icon**.
3. Select **Change how your mouse works** or **Make the mouse easier to use** option.
4. Tick the check box for **Prevent Windows from being automatically arranged when moved to the edge of the screen** with the mouse under “**Make it easier to manage windows**” section.